# slideshow like Apple's App Store

Tags: android, slideshow, imageswitcher

I want to create a slideshow in my android app that look like Apple's App Store one. functionally that I need is to change image automatically with an interval. also user can change image with swipe left or right. and there are preview for next and previous image. exactly like App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this library to implement the required functionality.
https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow